# strtol not detecting integer overflow

Tags: c, overflow, c99, strtol

I'm trying to convert a character array into an integer using strtol using the below code:

```
int foo = strtol(temp, (char **)NULL, 0);
```

Where temp = 4000000010

However strtol does not detect the overflow, it does not set foo to LONG_MAX and errno does not change from its inital value of 0.

Instead bob is changed to the overflowed value of -294967286.

So I was wondering what am I missing here?

Comment: Who is `bob` ? Did you really mean 0 as the base in strtol ?

Comment: @cnicutar: If 0 is specified as the base, then `strtol` infers the base according to the rules for integer literals.

Comment: @cnicutar: §7.20.1.4, paragraph 3, if you're curious.  (§7.21.1.4 in C11.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overflow probably occurs on the implicit `long` to `int` conversion in your statement, not inside `strtol()`.

Comment: Exactly right.  The questioner is on a platform where `long` is (likely) 64 bits wide and `int` is 32 bits wide.  The result of `strtol` does not overflow, but the conversion from `long` to `int` does, and the result is implementation defined.

Comment: @Stephen: How can you know what platform the OP is using? There is nothing in their post indicating this.

Comment: @Lundin: Indeed, the behavior OP described, if truthfully described, indicates this cause. There is no other possible cause on a correct implementation (aside from having invoked UB elsewhere :-).

Answer (score 0):

If you know you will get large numbers, why not use `strtoll` instead? Of course, like others remarked, then you definitively can't use an `int` to store the result.

Answer (score 0):

- You cannot store a variable of 4*10^9 in a 32-bit long. long is signed by default.
- The maximum value of a long is (2^32 / 2)-1 = 2147483674, assuming long is 32 bit on your system.
- Use **strtoul**() instead.
- Change foo to **unsigned long**.

Comment: This: "You cannot store a variable of 4*10^9 in a long," is not true in general (and in particular, it is not true for the platform on which the questioner's code is running).

Comment: @Stephen: Clarified that it can't be stored in a 32-bit long. Apart from that it is true.

Comment: If the OP's problem was that his `long` are 32-bit, then `strtol` would set `errno` to `ERANGE` and return a clamped value, as specified in C90 and C99.

Comment: Exactly.  As Pascal says, the observed behavior suffices to tell us that the questioner is not on a platform where `long` is 32-bits.